# Invertibility of $A+aI$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix, $I$ the identity matrix and $a$ a scalar. How can we find if $(A+aI)$ is invertible or not? How does it relate to $a$?

Comment: $A + aI$ is not invertible if and only if $-a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: What can you say about $\det(A+aI)$ if $-a$ is an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Are you familiar with the notion of an eigenvalue?  As the Comments by others suggest, it is a pivotal notion for finding "if $(A+aI)$ is invertible or not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Irrespective of whether $A$ is invertible, $A + aI$ will be invertible if and only if $\det(A + aI) \not= 0$. This determinant is a polynomial in $a$, and is thus nonzero for all but finitely many numbers $a$.